# Make All UIImageViews Point to Static UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, animation, scroll

I don't know if I'm thinking right or not, but my issue that I have custom cells (that look like as a cars) in UITableView, each cell contain 2 UIImageViews (wheel images), I need to rotate the Wheel Images when UITableView scrolling either downward of upward, so can I point all wheel images to one image, and then rotate this image immediately when UITableView is scrolling?

This is my code

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    CGPoint currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    if (currentOffset.y > self.lastContentOffset.y)
    {
        self.wheelImage.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.wheelImage.transform,- M_PI / 4);
    }
    else
    {
        self.wheelImage.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.wheelImage.transform, M_PI / 4);
    }
    self.lastContentOffset = currentOffset;
}
```

Sorry for my bad english, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best answer I have found till now, and it is work just fine, but I need to make it to more realistic (apply physical formula):

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    int fragment = 20;
    for(UITableViewCell *cell  in [self.showsTable visibleCells]){

        if ([cell isKindOfClass:[ShowCell class]]){

            CGPoint currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;

            if (currentOffset.y > self.lastContentOffset.y){

                [[(ShowCell*)cell wheel1Image] setTransform:CGAffineTransformRotate([(ShowCell*)cell wheel1Image].transform, M_PI / fragment)];
                [[(ShowCell*)cell wheel2Image] setTransform:CGAffineTransformRotate([(ShowCell*)cell wheel2Image].transform, M_PI / fragment)];
            }
            else{

                [[(ShowCell*)cell wheel1Image] setTransform:CGAffineTransformRotate([(ShowCell*)cell wheel1Image].transform,- M_PI / fragment)];
                [[(ShowCell*)cell wheel2Image] setTransform:CGAffineTransformRotate([(ShowCell*)cell wheel2Image].transform,- M_PI / fragment)];
            }
            self.lastContentOffset = currentOffset;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't do it such a way. What you need is to call `reloadData` for your `UITableView` from `scrollViewDidScroll` method. Calling `reloadData` will call `cellForRawAtIndexMethod`, and there in that method you should update transform of your wheels for every cell accordingly to current offset.

Comment: Thnx Andery for your response, but maybe your solution will make a performance issue and the scrolling will hang (I'm not sure, but I think this). I found another solution and I have posted, kindly tell me your feedback